# Parsing string representation of Bluetooth Service Data

Tags: macos, bluetooth

on macOS there is a file that contains information about connected Bluetooth devices.
I am using Swift and tried to connect to a device using a service identifier, but the connection attempt failed.

So i opened this file to check whether the actual service is supported by the device, but I don't know how to parse the data of the file.

Here are some examples:

```
<key>SupportedFeatures</key>
<data>
    h1v/2/6P//8=
</data>
```

What does this string mean or how can I obtain useful information about this?

Here is the (encrypted?) data of the supported Bluetooth Services:

```
<key>Services</key>
<data>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</data>
```

Before parsing the data using Swift, I would like to understand what this data means, so I would appreciate any help/hints or links.

Comment: Looks like base64 to me

Comment: You are right. It seems to be the Base64 encoded representation of a plist file.

Comment: As said, Base64, that's for sure. Then, if you decode it into String (UTF8), it says "bplist00������pqX$versionX$objectsY$archiverT$top" at the start, so seems to be a plist or a KeyArchivedData (Coding compliant) thing.